# Why am I getting gcloud.container.cluster.clusterSecondaryRange in body must be of type string: "null"

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, gcloud, google-anthos, kpt

I am following the steps for adding Anthos Service mesh provided [here](https://cloud.google.com/service-mesh/v1.6/docs/gke-install-asm#preparing_resource_configuration_files)

However, When I try running...

`kpt cfg list-setters asm`

I get...

```
error: The input value doesn't validate against provided OpenAPI schema: validation failure list:
gcloud.container.cluster.clusterSecondaryRange in body must be of type string: "null"
```

What is wrong? How would I debug?

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer but a workaround was to add these lines...

```
kpt cfg set asm gcloud.container.cluster.clusterSecondaryRange " "
kpt cfg set asm gcloud.container.cluster.servicesSecondaryRange " "
```